# Why did plsql_profiler produce no data rows?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
  v_run_no binary_integer;
  v_run_time_in_sec number;
BEGIN 
  dbms_profiler.start_profiler('Profiling my proc', 'Tom', v_run_no);

  schema.my_package.my_proc();

  dbms_profiler.stop_profiler();

  -- Calculate the TOTAL_TIME for each unit in the run by summing the TOTAL_TIME
  -- from each data record in the unit and writing it to the TOTAL_TIME column
  -- in the plsql_profiler_units table.
  dbms_profiler.rollup_run(v_run_no);

  -- Grab total run time for display
  SELECT r.RUN_TOTAL_TIME / 1000000000
  INTO v_run_time_in_sec
  FROM ucms_crim_conv.plsql_profiler_runs r
  WHERE r.RUNID = v_run_no;

  dbms_output.put_line('Profiled as run ' || v_run_no || ' in ' || v_run_time_in_sec || ' total sec.');
END;
```

I've run this same script to profile a different procedure call, by changing **ONLY** the `schema.my_package.my_proc();` line to call a different procedure, and everything went fine.

This time, after the script completes, I can see a row with a value in the `TOTAL_TIME` column for the run id in the `plsql_profiler_runs` table.

Previously I would also see 2 rows in `plsql_profiler_units`, one for the anonymous calling block, and 1 for the procedure being profiled, with associated rows in `plsql_profiler_data` for each unit.  However, this time, I see only the anonymous block in `plsql_profiler_units`, and the only `plsql_profiler_data` records for this run id are for the calling anonymous block, not the procedure itself, which is obviously what I'm interested in.

Why might this happen?  What can I do to fix it and see data for my procedure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the DBMS_PROFILER [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_profil.htm#i999855):

> Security Model
>
> The profiler only gathers data for units for which a user has CREATE
>   privilege; you cannot use the package to profile units for which
>   EXECUTE ONLY access has been granted. In general, if a user can debug
>   a unit, the same user can profile it. However, a unit can be profiled
>   whether or not it has been compiled DEBUG. Oracle advises that modules
>   that are being profiled should be compiled DEBUG, since this provides
>   additional information about the unit in the database.

I was able to reproduce your issue when profiled procedure was created in another schema and my profiling user lacked either `CREATE ANY PROCEDURE` or `ALTER ANY PROCEDURE` privileges. When he had both - everything ran just fine. Probably you reference another schema's package and suffer the same issue.

Comment: Dude, you are a lifesaver today!